# Unable to Html.Decode an encoded MvcHtmlString

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an extension method that is returning an `MvcHtmlString` which I realize is encoded. In certain cases I am tacking on query string parameters to the route. My desired result would look like this: `List/View/28?category=0&sort=Default`  however it is rendering the encoded string instead: `ListView/28%3fcategory%3d0%26sort%3dDefault`

In my C# and in my Razor code I have tried to decode it however it has no effect. Is there anything else I can try?

```
public static MvcHtmlString GenerateLanguageLink(this HtmlHelper html)
        {
            var routeDictionary = html.ViewContext.RouteData.Values;

            var queryStringCollections = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
            var queryStringText = string.Empty;
            if (queryStringCollections.Count > 0)
            {
                queryStringText = queryStringCollections.ToString();
                routeDictionary["Id"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(routeDictionary["Id"] + string.Format("?{0}", queryStringText));
            }

            return html.ActionLink(linkText, routeDictionary["action"].ToString(), routeDictionary["controller"].ToString(), routeDictionary, null);
        }
```

Razor:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@Html.GenerateLanguageLink().ToHtmlString()))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` from below

```
routeDictionary["Id"] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(routeDictionary["Id"] + string.Format("?{0}", queryStringText));
```

The code should be :

```
routeDictionary["Id"] = (routeDictionary["Id"] + string.Format("?{0}", queryStringText));
```

and leave the syntax in `Razor` like below

```
@Html.GenerateLanguageLink()
```

This will fix your issue.

Comment: I implemented your suggestions Kundan but I am still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just tacking on additional route values which apparently generates the proper query without me having to try and include the values and decode it.

```
    if (queryStringCollections.Count > 0)
    {
        queryStringText = queryStringCollections.ToString();
        routeDictionary["category"] = queryStringCollections[0];
        routeDictionary["sort"] = queryStringCollections[1];
    }
```

Although this doesn't answer my question, it is the proper way of doing this.